# How to extract a text and the text string associated with it in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I trying to extract specific text line using VBA. The program code must search and find for a keyword and then capture all the associated text/numbers/characters next/before/after that keyword

I tried the program for searching for a specific keyword and it worked out. Now I need to capture data that's before the keyword. Ex: Keyword is Treble. and the paragraph in the cell contains 03-Treble.
Now I need to extract the value 03 also alongside Treble. Like 03-Treble

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

  For Each cel In .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown))

     If cel.Value Like "*Treble*" Then
         Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value = "Treble"

     End If

  Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `cel.Offset(-1,0).value` would refer to value of Cell above and similarly  `cel.Offset(1,0).value` would refer to value of Cell below.

Comment: Thank you. I need to extract text string from within a single cell.

Comment: Your question has no sense. You need to extract 03 from "03-Treble" alongside Treble, and the output is gonna be 03-Treble? What are you really asking for?

Comment: Oops. trying to make things clear. 03-Treble is a part of a large paragraph. Like below. Now I need to extract only the 03-Treble part

Comment: We have mentioned our considerations.           
It contains following: 

03-Treble
09-Bass

Following are our considerations:

Comment: Please edit your question to provide examples of your data with desired output.  Please paste it as text (or use a Markdown Table Generator) as screenshots are difficult to copy/paste into Excel for testing.

Answer (score 0):

use [`Autofilter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) and [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) method of `Range` object

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter 1, "*Treble*"
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    .Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Resize(.Count).Replace what:="Treble*", lookat:=xlPart, Replacement:="Treble"
                End With
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not looking for output in message box. The output should contain only text with the prefix. For example, I have a paragraph in a single cell with text content 03-Treble. Now I want to get output as just 03-Treble in another sheet. '03' would be random. Like 03-Treble,04-Treble,55-Treble, while 'Treble' would be constant.

Comment: See edited answer. If it solves your question then you may consider marking it as accepted. Thank you